# How to show rectangle in listview item on mousehover event (winform C#)

Tags: c#

How can I display a description when I hover over an icon like in [this](https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/02/24/HOW.png) picture.
Since I use WinForms, i thought it might be possible with the `Mousehover` event on a `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Like on [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=netframework-4.8) explained:

```
// This example assumes that the Form_Load event handling method
// is connected to the Load event of the form.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Create the ToolTip and associate with the Form container.
   ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

   // Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
   toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
   toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
   toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
   // Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
   toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;

   // Set up the ToolTip text for the Button and Checkbox.
   toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "My button1");
   toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox1, "My checkBox1");
}
```

If you need more help, please share some code.

Comment: I want ask the background or rectangle same with the picture i attached